# Creating route widget

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I need to create new widget for android application. It must look like:

[image: example of widget]

Does anyone have idea how to do it?

Comment: Are you looking for a [tree view](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/figures/uiswing/components/tree.gif) kind?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't find similar realisation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to show you some discussions first. Go through [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/a-aukCotc_g). There you can find some discussions about why by you don't have that GUI option. [Here](http://code.google.com/p/tree-view-list-android/) is an example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it. Did you use it? Is there easy way to design it?

Comment: Yes I used, but didn't suit the needs. Yes there are ways to create it. Have look at [this](http://jatin4rise.wordpress.com/2011/07/05/dynamic-accordion-creation-in-android/) link this might give you some idea. Its basically accordion. But you can modify it to a tree view with some more efforts.